# filetype on or filetype off?

Tags: vim, pathogen

I use the `Pathogen` plugin for `gvim`. When configuring I set the following in my `vimrc` file:

```
call pathogen#infect()
call pathogen#helptags()
call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()

filetype on  "force reloading *after* pathogen loaded
```

Now I'm following **[this tutorial on Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YhqsjUUHj6g)** by Martin Brochhaus to set up Vim to be useful for Python coding and he suggests the following:

```
filetype off
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

So currently I have `filetype on` for pathogen but he is suggesting `filetype off`. What does this line of code do and how should I configure `vimrc` so Pathogen and Python are both happy?

Comment: Related question: [Why vundle requires filetype off](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14642956).

Comment: This is explained in *great* detail at [`:h filetypes`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html#filetypes).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()
```

is not needed at all: the function is deprecated and not useful anyway.

If you *really* need to be safe, this is what you should have at the top of your `~/.vimrc`:

```
" turn filetype detection off and, even if it's not strictly
" necessary, disable loading of indent scripts and filetype plugins
filetype off
filetype plugin indent off

" pathogen runntime injection and help indexing
call pathogen#infect()
call pathogen#helptags()

" turn filetype detection, indent scripts and filetype plugins on
" and syntax highlighting too
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

However, I've had the following for quite a while without any noticeable issue:

```
call pathogen#infect()
call pathogen#helptags()

filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

Comment: Agreed. Note that tpope [has updated](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/commit/532f0ca7d936f1229b926b73e84012a78c4f9800) the preferred `infect()` invocation, so these days it reads `execute pathogen#infect()`.

Answer (score 10):

The `:filetype off` is superfluous when immediately followed by `:filetype [plugin indent] on` (as it turns on filetype detection again, as described at `:help filetype-plugin-on`); don't blindly trust arbitrary resources on the Internet :-)

You usually want filetype detection (so that a corresponding syntax can be loaded for highlighting (with `:syntax on`)), and filetype-specific settings (the `plugin` part), and indentation rules (`indent`).

The only pitfall with Pathogen is that this should come *after* the Pathogen initialization, but you've done that right.

Comment: Nope, it isn't strictly superfluous. `:filetype off` does in fact do something quite specific, that is, it executes the `ftoff.vim` in the runtime files and this has real side-effects. For example it undefines an autocommand group which may have been set by a system vimrc.

Comment: @glts Technically correct, but (when run in a .vimrc at startup), the actions in `ftoff.vim` are undone by the `:filetype on`.

Comment: Not only technically, it may have real consequences: I was told that some Linux distros have `filetype on` in the system vimrc. In this situation, if you don't do `filetype off` and `on` again, it won't be possible to add ftdetect scripts in `~/.vim`. Fortunately, pathogen internally does `filetype off` so we don't have to worry about that.

Answer (score 4):

`filetype on` enables filetype detection.
Setting `filetype plugin` or `filetype indent` to `on` will turn on filetype detection if it wasn't already anyway. See `:help filetype`.

Comment: ok - seems a bit strange that in that tutorial he suggests `filetype off` - he doesn't say why - what would be the advantage of setting it to off?

Comment: @whytheq I know Vundle used to require this setting also as it caused an error when loading (but this was patched in vim). However I run Pathogen with vim myself without this line and haven't come across any trouble.