# vim plugins not loading: mac

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-plugin

I'm tring to load plugins for javascriopt and others.
I'm using `Vundle`
here is my `~/.vimrc`. (I'm using gvim on mac)

```
set nocompatible
filetype on

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize

" set t_Co=256
syntax on
set nu
set background=light
colorscheme solarized
set laststatus=2

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#rc()
" Declare all plugins here

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'

" The following are examples of different formats supported.
" Keep Plugin commands between vundle#begin/end.
" plugin on GitHub repo
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
" plugin from http://vim-scripts.org/vim/scripts.html
Plugin 'L9'
" Git plugin not hosted on GitHub
" Plugin 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git’

Plugin 'jelera/vim-javascript-syntax'
Plugin 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
Plugin 'nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides'
Plugin 'Raimondi/delimitMate'



" All of your Plugin must be added before the following line
filetype plugin indent on    " required
" To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
"filetype plugin on
"
" Brief help
" :Bundle       - lists configured plugins
" :Bundle    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :Bundle
" :Bundle foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
" :Bundle      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to auto-approve removal
"
" see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line
```

Directory structure at home ~/.vim

[image]

I'm using plugins suggested in [this link](http://oli.me.uk/2013/06/29/equipping-vim-for-javascript/)

This is the js file screen shot.

[image]

Any idea about where I'm lacking, please share.

Comment: In the second line, could you try changing `filetype on` to `filetype off`?

Comment: It won't work in that case as well.

Comment: after `call vundle#end() ` set filetype and syntax back on. Also I couldn't understand what exactly is not working. Also for reference you can take a look at my `.vimrc`: https://github.com/Roshanjossey/dot-files/blob/master/.vimrc

Comment: @sudobangbang thanks for the file. Your file is working but mine is completely weirdo. Do you feel anything I'm missing any step or code ?

Comment: I don't have enough information from the snippet you've shared above. I can't see any `call vundle#end()` there. Also I still don't know what the problem is

Comment: @sudobangbang I've used your vimrc still the plugin functionality is not working. Other settings are awesome, thanks for that. Color full status bar and few more information and thinks like that. No plugin...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130094/discussion-between-sudo-bangbang-and-pj1405).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of some syntax errors in `.vimrc` that Vundle is not working correctly. Older versions of vim needs

```
filetype off
```

before loading vundle plugins. Refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642956/why-vundle-requires-filetype-off) for more details.

Also `call vundle#end()` seems to be missing.

Please follow the following boiler plate and edit it according to your requirements.

```
set nocompatible
filetype off
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

" Let vundle manage itself:
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
" Syntax checking plugin
Plugin 'scrooloose/syntastic'

Plugin 'jelera/vim-javascript-syntax'
Plugin 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
Plugin 'nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides'
Plugin 'Raimondi/delimitMate'


call vundle#end() 

filetype plugin indent on " Filetype auto-detection
syntax on " Syntax highlighting
```